# How to show users how many downloads they made Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, model

In my app when the buyer buys something from the seller, the points from the buyer goes to the seller.
This is the logic in the controller (gig = is the product)

```
def downloadpage
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      if current_user.points >= @gig.pointsneeded 
        current_user.points -= @gig.pointsneeded
        @gig.user.points += @gig.pointsneeded
        current_user.save
        @gig.user.save
        redirect_to @gig.boxlink
      else
        redirect_to :back, notice: "You don't have enough points"
      end
    end
  end
```

> **Question:** How do I create a page that lists a user's  downloads/purchases?

Comment: you need to register whether user has downloaded something, and then show it

Comment: for example: 1. register with a download model `Download.create(user: current_user, downloadable: thing)`, 2. show, it comes from the Rails scaffold

Comment: so basically you advice to add to my "gig" model,a column called "download",and in my gig model,below(the above code), create something like ` def download---- @gigs = Download.create(user: current_user, download: gig)---end ` and in the view something like <%= current_user.gigs.download %> ?

Comment: no, not exactly, hmmm I did not understand.

Comment: Here is what i understood from your suggestion https://jsfiddle.net/ken1vaqz/ ,please note i wrote this based on your suggestion.To make myself even more clearer,i basically need to keep the record of the transactions,that the buyers makes,when he buys something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a join table to create a many-to-many relationship between products and users.

[image: database illustration]

In this case you might want to setup the relationship using a "join model" - that is a model which describes the relationship between users and products.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases, foreign_key: 'buyer_id'
  has_many :sales, foreign_key: 'seller_id', class_name: 'Purchase'
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases
  has_many :buyers, through: :purchases
  has_many :sellers, through: :purchases
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Examples of querying:

```
user.purchases 
user.purchases.first.product
user.purchases.this_month
```

You would need to modify your controller to do something like this:

```
def downloadpage
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    if current_user.points >= @gig.pointsneeded 
      @purchase = current_user.purchases.create(product: @gig, seller: @gig.user)
      if @purchase
       # ... transfer points between seller and buyer
      end
    end
  end
end
```

An action which lists the users purchases could look like this:

```
class PurchasesController
  def index 
    @purchases = current_user.purchases
  end
end
```

Comment: what if my app doesn't have buyer and seller,but just current_user and user? this is how my points exchange between user and current_user is made( because in my app any user can be a seller and buyer).How would change your code?

Comment: I don't think you are quite understanding this - in this example any User can be a buyers and seller many times over. Both the `seller_id` and `buyer_id` are just the ID of users. To set up a many-to-many relationship between Users you need a join table, which stores both parties in the transaction. You could call the columns and relation `user_id` and `current_user_id` - actually calling them buyer and seller just makes easier for your code to actually make sense to other people.

Comment: the association worked,but i can not show the title and the image of the gig, all i can do is `.count` method,of how many downloads.Please look at my "edit" from the question.Thank you for your help,i tried for a whole night to understand your advice.And finally almost got it)

Comment: Can you please ask a new question instead? This is not really in the scope of the original question anymore.

Comment: yes of course http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309248/getting-error-when-showing-the-purchases-of-the-user-when-showing-the-product-he