# Getting error when showing the purchases of the user,when showing the product he bought i get an error for product image and title

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, model

This is the relationship i have between User,Gig(product),and Purchase table that records the purchase.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gigs
  has_many :purchases, foreign_key: 'buyer_id'
  has_many :sales, foreign_key: 'seller_id', class_name: 'Purchase'
end

class Gig < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases
  has_many :buyers, through: :purchases
  has_many :sellers, through: :purchases
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gig
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User'
end
```

To record the purchase i use in my controller

```
 def downloadpage
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      if current_user.points >= @gig.pointsneeded 
        @purchase = current_user.purchases.create(gig: @gig, seller: @gig.user)
        if @purchase
          current_user.points -= @gig.pointsneeded
          @gig.user.points += @gig.pointsneeded
          current_user.save
          if @gig.user.save
            render 'successful_download', locals:{link:@gig.boxlink}
          end
        end
      else
        redirect_to :back, notice: "You don't have enough points"
      end
    end
  end
```

everything works when the buyer buys something from the seller,the points are transferred between accounts,and the buyer gets redirected to the final gig.

In my views i can do

```
<h1>You downloaded <%= current_user.purchases.count %> boxes</h1>
```

It will show the number of "gigs" the buyer made.

Now i want to show not just the number,but the title and the picture of the product he bought.This is what i tried

```
<div class="row experiment">
      <% current_user.purchases.each do |gig| %>
      <div class="well for-h1-gig-second col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 ">
        <%= link_to (image_tag gig.image.url(:medium), :class=>"img-responsive"), gig %>
        <h1><%= link_to gig.title, gig %></h1>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

But it says,that it can not find the image and the title.
so i tried `current_user.purchases.gig.each do |gig|`
without success.

> How do i fix it?
>   P.S: Please feel free to edit my title,for future readers,i couldn't formulate it better,thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that `current_user.purchases.each` iterates through purchases - not gigs.

```
<div class="row experiment">
    <% current_user.purchases.each do |purchase| %>
    <% gig = purchase.gig %>
    <div class="well for-h1-gig-second col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 ">
        <%= link_to(image_tag gig.image.url(:medium), :class=>"img-responsive"), gig %>
        <h1><%= link_to gig.title, gig %></h1>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Also to some of the other issues:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gigs # not going to work.
end
```

The reason it's not going to work is that the relation between `user` and `gig` goes through `purchases` and the `buyer_id` and `seller_id` foreign keys. Rails does not support relations that depend on multiple keys.

If you want to select gigs where the user is either seller or buyer you could use:

```
Gig.joins(:purchases).where('purchases.buyer_id=? OR purchases.seller_id=?', [current_user.id, current_user.id])
```

Comment: Where would you use your solution,in the gig controller? in the 'def downloadpage' action ?

Comment: also if i delete `has_many :gigs` i won't be able to use `current_user.gigs`,i tried removing it,and i can't use it anymore,it gives an error,without that line.

Comment: If you want to access the gigs sold/bought by user you could setup the relationship as in NoobExceptions answer. If you need both use `@gigs = Gig.joins(:purchases).where('purchas`...

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the association on user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases, foreign_key: 'buyer_id'
  has_many :gigs, through: :purchases, source: :buyer
  has_many :sales, foreign_key: 'seller_id', class_name: 'Purchase'
end
```

Then you should be able to loop through current_user.gigs

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention in my question,that i already have in my "user" model `has_many :gigs`,i tried to replace it with your suggestion,but it still gives an error that it can not find the image and the title of the product he bought.You said "to loop through current_user.gigs",i think it would show the gigs the user uploaded himself,not the ones he downloaded from another users,correct if i'm wrong.

Comment: Also with my current code i can use 'current_user.gigs' and it works,but shows the gigs the user uploaded,not the one he purchased.When i use 'current_user.purchases.count' it works and shows the number of downloads,but if i try to show the gigs,,with their title and image,it says that it can not find it,maybe it should be something like current_user.purchases.gigs ...but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You cant do current_user.purchases.gigs because your association is set the other way, a gig has many purchases, it would have to be current_user.gigs.purchases.

Comment: if i do current_user.gigs.purchases, it gives an error : undefined method `purchases',but if i do "current_user.gigs" or "current_user.purchases" it works.

Comment: Still not a good idea - the association name `gigs` is extremely ambiguous, and you can't really tell that its sold units without cracking the class open. `sold_gigs` which you used in your previous example was better.